# How to get the username from ADFS for a claims provider

Tags: security, saml, adfs

We have written a custom claims provider for ADFS. It's all working fine: you enter your username and credentials in our login page, and it authenticates you to ADFS. There's just one annoying omission: if you come from Office 365 portal and enter your email address, you get redirected to ADFS, then to our login page... but without the email address. You have to re-enter it before you can login.

I can't see anyway to request that ADFS forwards the email address as part of the SAML request, or to check if there is already an email address associated with the SAML request.

Regards
Robin Withey

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into the UID and Mail attributes of the SAML response...

```
<saml:Attribute Name="uid" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
  <saml:Attribute Name="mail" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
    <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">test@example.com</saml:AttributeValue>
  </saml:Attribute>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you are misunderstanding the problem: ADFS is effectively acting as a SP to our IdP, so it's sending a SAML request, not a response. We're the ones sending the SAML response.

Comment: Sorry my bad , however can you try to capture what is in the current form does asfs sends to the identity provider

Comment: Yes, done that: that's why I know it's not forwarding the username as part of the request. I'm trying to figure out whether there are claim rules that affect the request sent to the IdP/Claims Provider (as opposed to what is done with the response), or whether it's possible to send requests to ADFS for more information.

Comment: @RobinWithey we've got exactly the same issue. have you managed to find any solution?

Comment: Hi Kirill, Unfortunately not: we just have to go with entering the username twice.